# solve complex number equation

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

The equation in question is: $$(z-1)^4=(z+1)^4$$. From Euler's formula, I have shown that $$\frac{(1+(\cos x+i \sin x)^4)}{(1+(\cos x-i\sin x)^4)}=\cos(4x)+i\sin(4x)$$ which I thought could help me, but I'm not seeing how to apply this to my equation.

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting $z=\cos x+i\sin x?$  If yes, can we do that legally?

**Method**$\#1:$
Here is one of the ways: $$\left(\dfrac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^4=1=e^{2m\pi i}$$ where $m$  is any integer

$$\implies\dfrac{z-1}{z+1}=e^{2m\pi i/4}$$ where $m\equiv0,1,2,3\pmod4$

**Method**$\#2:$

Just expand to find $$z^4+\binom42z^2+1=0$$

Comment: yes, z is a complex number and I am working in polar form

Comment: @waldorf, See http://www.intmath.com/complex-numbers/4-polar-form.php

Comment: what do you mean by "mod 4"

Comment: @waldorf $0,\pi/2,\pi,3\pi/2,2\pi,・・・=i,-1,-i,1,i・・・$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$(z-1)^4=(z+1)^4\implies \left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^4=1=e^{2k\pi i}\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z$$

and now evaluate normally the $\;4\,-$ th roots of unity and etc.

Comment: thank you DonAntonio and lab, I will give it a go!

Comment: to verify, this method gives 4 roots 1, e^iπ/2, e^iπ, and e^i3π/2? (so 1, i, -i, -1)

Comment: @waldorf Indeed so...but those are the values for $\;\cfrac{z-1}{z+1}\;$ , **not** for $\;z\;$ . You still have some work to do...

Comment: ah ok-is it a case of rearranging?

Comment: @waldorf No, it is a case of equalling $\;\frac{z-1}{z+1}\;$ with each of the four roots you found and finding the value of $\;z\;$ in each case, if possible.

Comment: yep so equate then rearrange. However, I am then getting that z-1=z+1..how can't this be? thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @waldorf That means **that case** doesn't yield a solution...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59392/discussion-between-waldorf-and-donantonio).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  let $w=\cfrac{z-1}{z+1}\,$, then $0=w^4-1=(w^2-1)(w^2+1)=(w-1)(w+1)(w-i)(w+i)\,$.